# Comment is not displaying in django after submission

Tags: python, django

I have tried to submit a comment from app rather than django admin. Comment is not displaying when submitted from my created app. But it is displaying when I add a comment from django admin app. May be I am doing something wrong in views.py file. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.
views.py:

```
@login_required
def book_review(request,id):
book = get_object_or_404(Bookslist, id=id)
comment=Comment.objects.all().filter(post_id=id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user_id = request.user
        post.message= comment
        post.save()
        return redirect('book_review', id=id)
    else:
        form=CommentForm()
return render(request, "books/book_review.html", {'book':book, 'comment':comment, 'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
message= models.TextField('Message',null=True)
date_comment=models.DateTimeField(default=now, null=True)
user_id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
post_id=models.ForeignKey(Bookslist,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import Comment 

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['message', ]
```

book_review.html:

```
{% extends 'books/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'accounts/accounts.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class = "container">
<ul class = "nav nav-tabs" id = "myTab" role = "tablist">
   <li class = "nav-item">
      <a class = "nav-link active" id = "summary-tab" data-toggle = "tab" 
         href = "#summary" role = "tab" aria-controls = "summary" 
         aria-selected = "true">Summary</a>
   </li>
   <li class = "nav-item">
      <a class = "nav-link" id = "characters-tab" data-toggle = "tab" 
         href = "#characters" role = "tab" aria-controls = "characters" 
         aria-selected = "false">Characters</a>
   </li>
   <li class = "nav-item">
      <a class = "nav-link" id = "relatedbooks-tab" data-toggle = "tab" 
         href = "#relatedbooks" role = "tab" aria-controls = "relatedbooks" 
         aria-selected = "false">Related Books</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<div class = "tab-content" id = "myTabContent">
   <div class = "tab-pane fade show active" id = "summary" role = "tabpanel" 
      aria-labelledby = "summary-tab"><br><br>
      {{book.summary}}

    </div>
   
   <div class = "tab-pane fade" id = "characters" role = "tabpanel" 
      aria-labelledby = "characters-tab"><br><br>

      {{book.c1}}<br><br>{{book.c2}}<br><br>{{book.c3}}<br><br>{{book.c4}}<br><br>{{book.c5}}<br><br> 
   {{book.c6}}<br><br>{{book.c7}}<br><br>{{book.c8}}<br><br>{{book.c9}}<br><br>
      {{book.c10}}
     </div>
   
   <div class = "tab-pane fade" id = "relatedbooks" role = "tabpanel" 
      aria-labelledby = "relatedbooks-tab">Content for related books tab</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" class="mb-4">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Leave your comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
   </form>

{% for com in comment %}
<div class="card mb-2">
  <div class="card-body p-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="{% static 'images/icon2.webp' %}" alt="{{ com.user_id }}" class="w-100">
        <small>Posts: {{ com.count }}</small></div>
        <div class="col-10">
           <div class="row mb-3">
             <div class="col-6">
               <strong class="text-muted">{{ com.user_id }}</strong>
             </div>
             <div class="col-6 text-right">
               <small class="text-muted">{{ com.date_comment }}</small>
             </div>
           </div>
           {{ com.message }}<br><br>
           {% if com.user_id == user %}
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button>
           {% endif %}
      
   </div>
</div></div></div></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity = "sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin = "anonymous">
</script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity = "sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
crossorigin = "anonymous">
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity = "sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `post_id` to the newly created comment.

Like so:

```py
post.post_id = id
```

Also make sure you are using the correct naming for your variables i believe `post` should be `comment` in this scenario based on the form being of CommentForm: `model = Comment`

This replacement would make for sense for the code:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.user_id = request.user
        comment.message= comment
        comment.post_id = id
        comment.save()
```